# Which statistical test for "number of cases" with multiple, different group?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

I need your help to identify which statistical test I choose for my data.
I am analyzing if the "year of experience" of the nurse at the Triage, may influence the correct assignation of the "triage" code and, in case of "error", how much the experience can influence the variation in terms of under- or over-estimation.

In E.R. patients were accepted by the nurse who assigns them the first Triage Color, according to anamnesis, signs, and symptoms. Then, the Medical Doctor at the end of the examination may confirm or change the code assigned by the nurse.

My variables are:
Year of analysis, number of cases, Nurse triage code, MD triage code, Variation (Yes/No), Variation (-3 to +3 code from starting one), Operator, Experience (Year of assumption - the year of analysis).

For example we can have for operator 101:

```
year | N°Cases | Nurse code | MD Code  | Variation | Variation (n) | Operator | Experience 
2008 | 23      | CODE0      | CODE 0   |      NO   |    0          | 101      | 1
2008 | 12      | CODE0      | CODE 1   |      YES  |   +1          | 101      | 1
2008 | 53      | CODE1      | CODE 1   |      NO   |    0          | 101      | 1
2009 | 16      | CODE1      | CODE 0   |      YES  |   -1          | 101      | 2
2009 | 1656    | CODE2      | CODE 1   |      YES  |   -1          | 101      | 2
ETC…
```

I will try to explain more extensively my dataset observation.

Year of analysis Is the year analyzed for each hospitalization in the E.R.
Nurse triage code Is the first triage code given to patients by the nurse.
MD triage code is the final code assigned to patients by the MD.
The number of cases is the sum of all cases by the same year and the same operator for the groups gives by nurse triage and the MD triage code.
Variation (Yes/No) Represents the variation given by me to the nurse triage code.
Variation (-3 to +3 code from starting one) represent  the amplitude of this variation (eg: from code2 to code 0=-2.) Operator is the Id of the nurse
Experience (Year of assumption - the year of analysis of the nurse).

My Target is to search if the experience of the nurse may influence his ability to assign the same code of the MD.
Secondary, I will investigate how and how much the nurse experience may influence the amplitude of the variations.

Looking at my dataset example, you can see that in the second row there was a variation of 1 code. Also in the 4 rows, the variation was 1, but there is a huge difference between the two rows!
The first case was a mild urgent patient’s condition (MD CODE 1) underestimate as a nonurgent one (NURSE CODE0). In the second case patient’s symptoms were overestimate. Although the variation was the same (1 code) the conditions are really different. I think that each combination of nurse and MD CODE can be considered as different entities (like groups), without this may generate some bias due to unbalance between groups.

I was thinking about Poisson Regression Analysis, but I think it may not be the best way to investigate all the aspects of my data. I am not statistical, but studying a little I found that Poisson regression is used to predict a dependent variable that consists of "count data" given one or more independent variables. Nevertheless, I am not able to understand how I can replay My primary and secondary target with this analysis, and I am starting to think I should search for a different type of test.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to improve your question.  It's not clear what each observation in your dataset represents. You also included "number of cases" and "multiple, different groups" in the title of the question, but then talk about analyzing the relationship between "year of experience" and "triage code" in the text.  What is the dependent variable in your analysis?  Why were you considering Poisson regression, and what makes you think it may not be the right approach?

Comment: Dear Alexk, Thanks for your reply. I will try to explain more extensively my dataset observation.